# What is lacking in my geometric calculation below?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

The objective is to align the baseline of a label with the bisector. I want to summarize 4 possible tricks as follows. Let me know if there is another trick beyond my consideration.

### The first trick:

Here I use `\rput{(B)}(0,0){\mylabel}` and the objective is well done.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt,multi,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset
{
    saveNodeCoors,
    CurveType=polyline,
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    MarkAngleRadius=1.6,
    LabelSep=1,
}

\newcommand{\mylabel}{$\scriptscriptstyle180^\circ-\theta$}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \pstGeonode(1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{\rput{(B)}(0,0){\mylabel}}
    \rput(3,5.5){\tiny rput\{(B)\}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### The second trick:

I use `\rput{!\psGetNodeCenter{B} B.y B.x atan}(0,0){\mylabel}` and the objective is also well done.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt,multi,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset
{
    saveNodeCoors,
    CurveType=polyline,
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    MarkAngleRadius=1.6,
    LabelSep=1,
}

\newcommand{\mylabel}{$\scriptscriptstyle180^\circ-\theta$}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \pstGeonode(1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{\rput{!\psGetNodeCenter{B} B.y B.x atan}(0,0){\mylabel}}
    \rput(3,5.5){\tiny rput\{!psGetNodeCenter\{B\} B.y B.x atan\}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### The third trick:

I use the numerical literal of node `B`, `\rput{!5 5 atan}(0,0){\mylabel}` and I failed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt,multi,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset
{
    saveNodeCoors,
    CurveType=polyline,
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    MarkAngleRadius=1.6,
    LabelSep=1,
}

\newcommand{\mylabel}{$\scriptscriptstyle180^\circ-\theta$}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \pstGeonode(1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{\rput{!5 5 atan}(0,0){\mylabel}}
    \rput(3,5.5){\tiny rput\{!5 5 atan\}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### The fourth trick:

I use the saved coordinates of node `B`, `\rput{!N-B.y N-B.x atan}(0,0){\mylabel}` and I failed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt,multi,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset
{
    saveNodeCoors,
    CurveType=polyline,
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    MarkAngleRadius=1.6,
    LabelSep=1,
}

\newcommand{\mylabel}{$\scriptscriptstyle180^\circ-\theta$}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \pstGeonode(1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{\rput{!N-B.y N-B.x atan}(0,0){\mylabel}}
    \rput(3,5.5){\tiny rput\{!N-B.y N-B.x atan\}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Question:

Herbert had said that there is an inverse transformation that I have to think about when working with `\rput` and `\psGetNodeCenter`. I forgot the exact statement and the link.

Shortly speaking, what is lacking in my PostScript expression for the 3rd and 4th tricks?

Comment: I think the question to be asked is why the first two tricks actually work.  Do you have the documentation for them?

Comment: The problem with the second two tricks is that the angle is not being calculated with respect to the position of the vertex and the "center" of the circle.

Comment: @A.Ellett: There is no documentation. I got it by a trial and error approach.

Comment: The first two seem to work because a vector is being calculated from the position of the "center" of the angle to the vertex of the angle.  Thus the alignment works.

Comment: Also, while `\pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{\rput{(B)}(0,0){\mylabel}}` works, `\pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{\rput{(5,5)}(0,0){\mylabel}}` doesn't.  .... which kind of debunks my *vector* idea.

Comment: @A.Ellett: The behaviour of `\rput` is mysteriously implemented.

Comment: Actually, I think the vector idea is correct.  With `\rput{(B)}` the coordinates for `B` are retrieved relative to the current position.  With `\rput{(5,5)}` the coordinates are relative to the anchor `(0,0)` for the `\rput`.

Comment: It's not *so* mysterious.  Most of what's happening is happening in the postscript coding for these commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both instances, you're only calculating the angle relative to `(0,0)` which, for `B` (or `(5,5)`) is @ 45 degrees. That's why the angle mark is lighting up with the 45 degree line segment AB. Here are the ways to correctly implement options #3 and #4:

### The third trick:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt,multi,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-eucl
\psset
{
    saveNodeCoors,
    CurveType=polyline,
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    MarkAngleRadius=1.6,
    LabelSep=1,
}

\newcommand{\mylabel}{$\scriptscriptstyle180^\circ-\theta$}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \pstGeonode(1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{\rput{!5 5 atan 5 1 sub 5 4 sub atan add 2 div}(0,0){\mylabel}}
    \rput(3,5.5){\tiny rput\{!5 5 atan\}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### The fourth trick:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt,multi,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-eucl
\psset
{
    saveNodeCoors,
    CurveType=polyline,
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    MarkAngleRadius=1.6,
    LabelSep=1,
}

\newcommand{\mylabel}{$\scriptscriptstyle180^\circ-\theta$}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \pstGeonode(1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{\rput{!N-B.y N-B.x atan N-B.y N-C.y sub N-B.x N-C.x sub atan add 2 div}(0,0){\mylabel}}
    \rput(3,5.5){\tiny rput\{!N-B.y N-B.x atan\}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

In essence, both methods calculate the average angle between the two line segments AB and CB:

- Line segment AB (relative to the origin `(0,0)`) is @ angle 45 (or `5 5 atan`);
- Line segment BC (relative to the origin `(0,0)`) is @ angle arctan (5-1)/(5-4) = arctan 4/1 (or `4 1 arctan`).

In method four, a more symbol approach is used, namely the saved node coordinates. Both methods and with an average of the two angles between line segment AB and BC, hence the use of `add 2 div`.